# Can this be in one query: SELECT x as y1 WHERE y = 1 and SELECT x as y2 WHERE y = 2?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

Given a table like

```
id   x     y
--  ---   ---
5   200    1
5   3000   2
5   224    3
6   135    1
6   2222   2
6   16     3
```

I can get all the x values where y = 1 with

```
SELECT x as y1 
WHERE y = 1
```

and I can get all the x values where y = 2 with

```
SELECT x as y2 
WHERE y = 2
```

but I would like to select these in one query so I get a result like

```
id   y1    y2
--  ---   ---
5   200    3000
6   135    2222
```

Can this be done in one query?

I've tried pretty much every variation I can think but all errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL does not have a `PIVOT` function just like `SQL Server`. But still you can simulate it using `MAX()` and `CASE()` to test its value with in a row.

```
SELECT  ID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN y = 1 THEN x END) y1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN y = 2 THEN x END) y2
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b627f/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦═════╦══════╗
║ ID ║ Y1  ║  Y2  ║
╠════╬═════╬══════╣
║  5 ║ 200 ║ 3000 ║
║  6 ║ 135 ║ 2222 ║
╚════╩═════╩══════╝
```

Comment: Thank you J W! That was perfect, and astoundingly fast... and with a demo to boot. (By the way, I'm trying to understand why MAX is needed. When I take it away Y2 becomes null in both cases... not sure why.)

Comment: see the result of this to understand more, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b627f/6 basically `MAX()` or `MIN()` both gives you the same result

Comment: I see, without MAX, it GROUPs the first values, not the max values. Thank you again for your awesome help!